# How to add input elements into a form when clicking a button and how to process it in laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am currently trying to make a simple event management platform (eg: ticketmaster, eventbrite) with laravel 5.

So now i am trying to create the create event page, where people can input their event data on this page, and i want to show Add Ticket Button which will add an input forms automatically in the page without refreshing the page, so that the data typed in the previous fields wont be lost.

I don't know how to describe it in texts, so i'll try to explain it through the codes.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/event" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!--
    This is the part where i put the event information input fields,
    and because it's very long and irrelevant to this question,
    i decided to not put it here.
-->

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Tickets</h3>
                <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--
                Below is the codes block i want to be automatically added when people click the Add Ticket Button.
            -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input name="ticket_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ticket Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <input name="ticket_qty" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input name="ticket_price" type="text" class="form-control">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/organizer/">
                            <i class="ion-android-delete"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--
                Above is the codes block i want to be automatically added when people click the Add Ticket Button.
            -->

            <div class="box-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-warning">
                    Add Free Ticket
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-info">
                    Add Paid Ticket
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create Event">
</div>

</form>
```

So this is some preview of what that codes looks like when people havent clicked the add ticket button:

[View when button havent clicked yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Exu.png)

Then when people click the add ticket button, it will be like this:

[View when button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KW1S.png)

I want to set the max rows into 5 rows, so when people have clicked the add ticket button more than 5 times, it will not add any new rows. And also when people click the delete button, it will remove the code blocks as well.

To create something like what i mentioned above, should i use ajax? or general javascript is enough? Which one is the best approach in my case?

And also how do i catch the data in the laravel controllers?

Thankyou very much, have a great day. :)

Comment: This is easily done in jQuery. Just add event handlers to the buttons and run a function to add the new rows. I never worked with laravel, so I can't say how it integrates with that, but it probably won't bee too much of an issue. Please provide code snippets so we can provide you with code examples.

Comment: @Battle_707 alright, i'll try put some code. please hold on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create each row (let's call them components) programatically via javascript, inject them into some element inside a `<form>` and send the data via ajax. Let's say you have a javascript function to create the components. For sake of simplicity, each component is a set of `<input type="text">`.

```js
function createTicketComponent(type) {
  type = type || null;

  var elements    = [],
      rootElement = document.createElement('tr'),
      price       = type === 'FREE' ? 0 : '';

  elements.push('<td><input type="text" name="tickets[][name]" /></td>');
  elements.push('<td><input type="text" name="tickets[][qty]" /></td>');
  elements.push(price === 0 ? type : '<td><input type="text" name="tickets[][price]"/></td>');
 
  rootElement.innerHTML = elements.join('');
  
  return rootElement;
}


function createFreeTicketComponent() {
  return createTicketComponent('FREE');
}


function onClickCreateTicketButton(event) {
  var button    = event.target,
      container = document.querySelector('#tickets'),
      component;

  if(button.classList.contains('free')) {
    component = createFreeTicketComponent();
  } else {
    component = createTicketComponent();
  }

  container.appendChild(component);
}


var buttonsGroup = document.getElementById('create-ticket-buttons');
buttonsGroup.addEventListener('click', onClickCreateTicketButton);
```

```html
<form>
  <table id='tickets'>

  </table>
</form>

<div id="create-ticket-buttons">
    <button class='create-ticket free'>FREE TICKET</button>
    <button class='create-ticket'>PAID TICKET</button>
    <button class='create-ticket'>DONATION</button>
</div>
```

On the PHP side, just get the tickets as an array.

```
$tickets = $request->input('tickets');
# OR
$tickets = $_POST['tickets'];
```

Well, this is just an idea... and the code is nearly a pseudocode.
Anyways... I hope it helps.

**UPDATED**

First of all, you should add an id attribute in the `.box-body` element.

```
<div id='tickets' class='box-body'>
    <!-- all the .row elements will be here -->
</div>
```

Then, in the `createTicketComponent` function:

```
function createTicketComponent(type) {
  type = type || null;

  var rootElement = document.createElement('div');
      rootElement.setAttribute('class', 'row');


  var contents = '<div class="col-xs-4">
        <input name="ticket_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ticket Name">
      </div> ... ETC ETC ETC';


  rootElement.innerHTML = contents;

  return rootElement;
}
```

And finally, change the HTML where the buttons are placed:

```
<div id="create-ticket-buttons" class="box-footer">
    <a class="btn btn-warning create-ticket free"> Add Free Ticket</a>
    <a class="btn btn-info create-ticket">Add Paid Ticket</a>
</div>
```

Yes, you should use an array in the name attribute for each input field, so that in the PHP side you can get each one of them.

```
<input type="text" name="tickets[][name]"/>
<input type="text" name="tickets[][qty]"/>
<input type="text" name="tickets[][price]"/>
```

Comment: i think this is what im looking for. but how to do it in my case? I have edited my post and put some codes in it, would you please teach me how to do it in this case? and should i name the fields with array? (something like <input type="text" name="ticket_name[]"/> Thanks btw :)

Comment: after hours trying to implement your codes i finally succeed. Thanks very much man. :) But there is still some few things, how to remove the components created when user click the remove ticket button? Much thanks before!

Comment: wow thanks very much man. thats really awesome, just like what i expected. But i suddenly thought of, to show a confirmation dialog before it actually removes the components, is it possible? it will be just so perfect if it could. but thanks very much man, i really appreciate your helps. Have a great day :)

Comment: You just need to add a conditional with a `confirm("are you sure?")` on the delete link's click event...

Comment: i make it like this. it did shows a confirmation message, but no matter what i choose (ok or cancel) it still deletes it. am i doing it wrong?
function onClickTicket(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var element = event.target;

  if(element.classList.contains('delete-ticket')) {
   if(confirm("are you sure?"))
    element.parentNode().remove();
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Fernando, below is an example of a jQuery function you can call to add a row to your table:

```
function  addRow (isFree)
{
    var newRow = $('<div>', {class: "row"});
    newRow.append($('<div>', {class: "col-xs-4"})
            .append($('<input>', {type: "text", name: "ticket_name[]", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Ticket Name"}));
    newRow.append($('<div>', {class: "col-xs-2"})
            .append($('<input>', {type: "text", name: "ticket_qty[]", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Quantity"}));
    newRow.append($('<div>', {class: "col-xs-3"})
            .append($('<span>', {class: "input-group-addon"}).append("$")
            .append($('<input>', {type: "text", name: "ticket_price[]", class: "form-control"})
            .append($('<span>', {class: "input-group-addon"}).append(".00"));
    newRow.append($('<div>', {class: "col-xs-3"})
            .append($('<a>', {class: "form-control", href: "/organizer/"}).append($('<i>',{class: "ion-android-delete"})));

    $('.box-body').append(newRow);
}
```

You will also have to add the appropriate event handlers to the buttons to call the function:

```
$('.box-footer a.btn-warning').on('click', function () { addRow(true); });
$('.box-footer a.btn-info').on('click', function () { addRow(false)});
```

I can't quite see what the difference is in HTML code between the free and paid tickets, so I haven't added that code, but in the function simply add the code to modify the elements/ values in the row when yo detect that `isFree` is true.

I condensed the code quite a bit, so let me know if you have a hard time reading it. Also, please not that your first HTML code (as shown in your question) should pass the inputs as an array, as shown in the various comments/ answers to this post.

Comment: I have tried the codes, but no luck it didnt work. :(

Below is how i wrote it: